# uploading images and send to ajax but FormData append not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been trying to solve this code but still not sending the result images
can any one tell me what is the problem wit this code. all am getting in console is  `gallery[], [object File]`

```
                var storedFiles = [];

            var input_file = document.getElementById('fields_gallery');
            $('#fields_gallery').change(function(e) {
                for (i = 0; i < input_file.files.length; i++) {
                    var readImg = new FileReader();
                    var file = input_file.files[i];

                    // var fileExtension = '.' + file.name.split('.').pop(); //got the file extestion
                    // var outputfile = file.name.substr(0, file.name.lastIndexOf('.')) || file.name; //got the file name
                    // var newFileName = randomString(26, 'n') + fileExtension;

                    // Object.defineProperty(file, 'name', {
                    //     writable: true,
                    //     value: newFileName
                    // });

                    if (file.type.match('image.*')) {
                        storedFiles.push(file);
                        
                        readImg.onload = (function(file) {
                            return function(e) {
                                $('#upload_images').append(
                                    '<div id = \"' + file.name + '\" class=\'pip col-2 position-relative\'>' +   
                                        '<input type=\"hidden\" class=\"hidden_image\" name=\"fields[gallery][]\" value=\"'+ file.name +'\">' +                              
                                        '<img class=\"thumbnail img-thumb\" src=\"' + e.target.result + '\" />' + 
                                        '<span file=\"' + file.name + '\" class=\"remove position-absolute top-0 end-0 bg-danger text-white me-1\">X</span>' +
                                    '</div>'
                                );
                                $('.remove').click(function(e){
                                    $(this).parent('.pip').remove();

                                    var filename = $(this).parent().attr('file');
                                    for(var i = 0; i < storedFiles.length; i++) {
                                        if (storedFiles[i].name == filename) {
                                            storedFiles.splice(i, 1);
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            };
                        })(file);
                        readImg.readAsDataURL(file);
                    }
                }

                var formData = new FormData();
                for(var i = 0; i < storedFiles.length; i++) {
                    formData.append('files[]', storedFiles[i]);
                    console.log(storedFiles[i]);
                }
                
                $.ajax({
                    url : '" . App('url')->link('node/admin/node', 'op=ajax&action=upload') . "',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
            });
```

trying to upload images and renamed the images name not on submitting it't not giving me the result of images

Comment: It would be useful to have the HTML that you are using to e able to determine the actual issue. To all intents and purposes the above seems to work

Comment: fyi: using `file = \"' + file.name + '\"` as an attribute is not valid - instead you should use a dataset attribute

Comment: with storedFiles is giving me the right result but with formData.append not sending the latest result instead the old filename

Comment: This is what am getting in the console `(2) ['files[]', File]
0
: 
"files[]"
1
: 
File {name: '89393458127054808287958631.jpg', lastModified: 1703637592907, lastModifiedDate: Wed Dec 27 2023 00:39:52 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 107829, …}
length
: 
2`

Comment: `FormData` should be used with AJAX but there is no AJAX shown here. Within the `readImg.onload` callback you generate HTML including a hidden field - what is the point of that if you are using FormData somehow?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius, i have added the ajax